# How to call Confirmation box in IF condition from Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using a LinkButton and a DropDown.

When I click on the LinkButton the DropDown appears.

After selecting a DropDown value, I want a confirmation box called from JavaScript to appear, ensuring that the value is changed.

I'm calling this script in the second `if` condition, but it's not working.

After the confirmation I want to change the other value and exit from the condition.

```
protected void lnkbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((ddlHiringManager.SelectedItem != null &&
        (ddlHiringManager.SelectedItem.Text != lblHiringManager.Text)) &&
        (Convert.ToInt32(ddlHiringManager.SelectedValue)) != -1)
    {

        if (ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Confirm", "<script type='text/javascript'>Confirm('Are you sure you want to change Hiring Manager for this requirement.');</script>"))
        {
            ClsClientManager objClientManager = new ClsClientManager();

            if (objClientManager.UpdateHRManagerByReqID(Convert.ToInt32(hdnReqId.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ddlHiringManager.SelectedValue)) > 0)
            {
                lblShowHiringManager.Text = ddlHiringManager.SelectedItem.Text;
            } 
        }      
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please Select Hiring Manager !');</script>");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use UpdatePanel on the page? And did the lnkBtnSave.Click is an ajax post back?

Comment: hi  Ali .NET, i m not using update panel not a ajax post pack i m calling simple JS confirmation box

Comment: why you need to do it from code behind , why not do it client side

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartup script returns void, so it couldn't be used with logical expression (if). Looking to your code I wonder if you are not getting compile time error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'"?

Comment: hi tariq, i m doing it from client side but when i press no in confirmation box then it going else condition also which i don't want because in else i have another script which alert to user for select the value

Comment: ya  Ali .NET i m getting same error.. so that i want solution

Comment: i dont think startup script can be used like that, how will browser be sending the return value from confirmation to the server side. Better check this thing client side that is as soon as the user selects some value from the dropdownlist

Comment: right tariq, but when i returing value from client and confirmation also appear in else condition also...i call confirmation box only if first if is true

Comment: Code Behind is executed and ended before anything is sent to the browser. It just doesn't work like that. JavaScript is executed client side, Code Behind (!) is executed server side. They do not interact and do not run intertwined.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the result of `RegisterStartupScript` method.

Change ASPX page code for the LinkButton as given below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnSave_Click"
    OnClientClick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to change Hiring Manager for this requirement.');">Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have added the client side click event.

On clicking the LinkButton you will get the confirmation box. The page will postback only if you click `OK` in the confirmation box.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this Code Snippet. On dropdown selected index change event

```
 protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Are you sure, you want to upload leave ?";
    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);
}
```

And for Client Side declare that method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmApproval(objMsg) {
        if (confirm(objMsg)) {
            $('#divUploadLeave').fadeTo('slow', .6);
            return true;
        } else {

            $('#divUploadLeave').fadeTo('slow', 1);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Hope It helps you.

Still if you want all things on Client Side please let me know.

Comment: No probs Sandeep please use same code on Link button .. Only Events are change functionality were same.

Comment: Sandeep i have Write Same code its working fine    protected void lnkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Are you sure, you want to upload leave ?";
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);

    }

Comment: what is that neeraj "#divUploadLeave" in script.?i have given my control id but its not calling script

Comment: Sandeep this is exact name of Control Id which i give in my test application .Please use this code for your id " $('[id*="YourAspControlId"]')" to get your control.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29469/discussion-between-sandeep-and-neeraj-dubey)

Answer (score -1):

Please add return before `Confirm` this will solve your issue.

```
 **if (ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Confirm", "<script type='text/javascript'>return Confirm('Are you sure you want to change Hiring Manager for this requirement.');</script>"))**
```

Comment: That won't satisfy compiler, he will again get compilation error.